# Kubernetes Ingress: Expose only few paths in REST API

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a Service which have the following paths (as example):

- /api/Private1
- /api/Private2
- /api/Private3
- /api/Public1
- /api/Public2

Is it possible to only expose /api/Public1 and /api/Public2?

So far, the only thing that worked for me is below, but I'm not sure if it is the proper approach:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: txc-dev-public-exposition
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/Public1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: messaging-dev.myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /gateway/api/Public1
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: gatewayapi-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

If I call https://messaging-dev.myapp.com/api/Public1, it routes properly. But how to handle query parameters, etc?

Is it possible to do above?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression in the path:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: txc-dev-public-exposition
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/Public$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: messaging-dev.myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /gateway/api/Public(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: gatewayapi-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

`$1` in the rewrite path is substituted with the capture group `(.*)` from the path.