# Kubernetes Ingress: Expose multiple API paths

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a Service which have the following paths (as example):

```
/api/weatherforecast
/api/weatherforecast/echomyname/name
/api/employee
/api/employee/getemployeebyid/1
```

my nginx ingress has public IP and I want to be able to reach out to these API's

I have tried this but with no luck, I can reach API's when I add public load balancer, so the service is working as expected, this is the code for the ingress that I am trying

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: weather-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: weather-app
            port:
              number: 80
```

What do I need to change here in order to get it working, I am not even getting 404.

Comment: Please try these two recommendation and check once
First approach is modify you path value to  path: /(.*) and check once

And if that is not working then please try /api/weatherforecast(/|$)(.*) once and let me know.
The logic behind this is it will try to match the entire path after the base URL. The nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2 then uses $2 to reference the captured part of the path and rewrite the request to the backend service.

Comment: Tried both, neither are working...

Comment: Hmm.. I found a similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74644333/kubernetes-ingress-expose-only-few-paths-in-rest-api Marko.

Comment: Yup, I have checked that also, but no luck.

Comment: Just for testing, can we simplify the path and check.

  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: your-public-ip
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/weatherforecast
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: servicenname1
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /api/weatherforecast/echomyname/name
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: servicename2
            port:
              number: 80

I am just trying to help you.